# ANGULARJS: How to add 0 if ng-repeat is empty?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My table looks like this:
[image]

and the code behind that is:

```
<tr ng-repeat="di in dayInterval track by di.id"
          ng-class="{weekend: di.dayName=='Samedi'|| di.dayName=='Dimanche'}">

          <!--td ng-repeat="pr in profiles track by pr.i.id_profile" ng-if="gr.id_groupe==pr.i.groupe"
          style="min-width:150px !important; max-width:150px !important; height:40px !important;font-size:12px;">

            <!label ng-repeat="ptt in value.ptasks track by ptt.id_profile" ng-if="ptt.id_profile==pr.i.id_profile">
              {{ptt.counter / 2}}
            </label-->

            <td ng-repeat="(key,value) in fullTasks track by value.id_profile" style="min-width:150px !important; max-width:150px !important; height:40px !important;font-size:12px;"
            ng-if="gr.id_groupe==value.groupe">
                <div ng-repeat="d in value.tasks track by $index" ng-if="d.from_interval==di.dsUnix">
                  <a style="color:rgb(0, 102, 255); font-weight:bolder">{{d.counter / 2}} {{d.hrname}}</a>
                </div>
              0

            </td>




          </tr>
```

How do I auto generate the 0 value for each person only if there's no value on that td?

Comment: I'm not sure which line it is, but I think you can have just that `{{d ? d.counter/2 : 0}}`. If `d` exists (not empty), it will divide by two, otherwise show a zero

Answer (score 1):

I usually just do this:

```
<div ng-show="value" ... rest of attrs here></div>
<div ng-show="!value">0</div>
```